# My software center won't even start

Tags: package-management, software-center

My software center won't even start. It is giving me an error message. I've attached with this post the screenshot of the error message.

[image]

I'm new to Ubuntu. It would be helpful if I can get step by step instructions to solve the issue.

Comment: Please don't repost the same question.